# Using Intent to display listview in dialog themed layout

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, arraylist

I am having this crazy error with displaying an arraylist from my main activity to a listview in a dialog layout of another activity.

Here is the error I am getting over and over that is causing the screen to stay black.  Whenever I hit my home button on my phone though, I can briefly see the dialog window with the populated listview inside:

```
10-28 00:28:43.735    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:43.755    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:43.765    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:43.825    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:43.855    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:43.885    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-28 00:28:43.895    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-28 00:28:43.895    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-28 00:28:43.925    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
10-28 00:28:43.925    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:43.925    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
10-28 00:28:43.925    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:43.935    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.165    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.205    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.325    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.355    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-28 00:28:44.365    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-28 00:28:44.375    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-28 00:28:44.415    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
10-28 00:28:44.415    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.415    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
10-28 00:28:44.415    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.445    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.455    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.495    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.535    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.576    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-28 00:28:44.576    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-28 00:28:44.586    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-28 00:28:44.626    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
10-28 00:28:44.626    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.626    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
10-28 00:28:44.626    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.646    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.656    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.696    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.746    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.876    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-28 00:28:44.876    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-28 00:28:44.886    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-28 00:28:44.896    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
10-28 00:28:44.896    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.906    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
10-28 00:28:44.906    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.916    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-28 00:28:44.926    9480-9480/my.obd2connector D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
```

Here is how I am populating it all from MainActivity.

My OnStart:

```
protected void onStart()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    lanchPairedDevices();
}
```

The launchPairedDevices:

```
public void lanchPairedDevices()
{
   Intent i = new Intent(this,PairedDevices.class);
   i.putExtra("arrayListPaired", arrayListpaired);
   i.putExtra("arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices", arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices);
   startActivity(i);
}
```

Creating the Arraylist in the MainActivity:

```
public class BluetoothActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ListView listViewPaired;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListpaired;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter,detectedAdapter;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices;
    ListItemClickedonPaired listItemClickedonPaired;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListBluetoothDevices = null;
    ListItemClicked listItemClicked;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        listViewDetected = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDetected);
        listViewPaired = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewPaired);
        arrayListpaired = new ArrayList<String>();
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        listItemClickedonPaired = new ListItemClickedonPaired();
        arrayListBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(BluetoothActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListpaired);
        detectedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BluetoothActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        listViewDetected.setAdapter(detectedAdapter);
        listItemClicked = new ListItemClicked();
        detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listViewPaired.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

The Paired Devices class that is displaying the ArrayList from MainActivity in a dialog:

```
public class PairedDevices extends BluetoothActivity {
    ListView listViewPaired;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_paired_devices);
        listViewPaired = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewPaired2);
        listViewPaired.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        getPairedDevices();
        listViewPaired.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClickedonPaired);
    }
}
```

And finally the getPairDevices method the PairedDevices calls from BluetoothActivity:

```
public void getPairedDevices() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        if(pairedDevice.size()>0)
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice)
            {
                arrayListpaired.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.add(device);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: adapter = new Adapter();listViewPaired.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: I would call this in the PairedDevices class?  It says Adapter is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

Comment: adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(BluetoothActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListpaired);
        detectedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BluetoothActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);

Comment: detectedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BluetoothActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice); where is the arraylist to display

Comment: Hmmm i don't really understand, the detectedAdapter is for a different arraylist I am not using right now.